# Winforms: Update label on Form from another class

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, label, progress

I have a project where I need to update a labels text from inside another classes method. It's worth noting that this method is being called from a Background worker thread.

I have tried passing in the text to update as a UserState Obj in the Workers ReportProgress(); method and then updating the label when the workers progress changed event is fired off on the main form. This works, but obviously only updates the labels text when the progress changed event is raised.

I have code that's loading/removing proxies constantly and I need a label to show this as it happens (as opposed to only updating when the bg workers progress changed event fires). Hopefully someone can help.

Thanks

Edit* Here's some code to make the problem a little easier to understand: -

```
  public string Request(string action)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action))
        {
            return "";
        }

        HttpWebRequest req;

        string response = string.Empty;
        while (response.Equals(string.Empty) && proxy != null)
        {
            try
            {
                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
                req.Proxy = proxy;
                response = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RemoveProxy(proxy);
                MessageBox.Show("Proxy Removed: " + proxy.Address.ToString());

                proxy = GenNewProx();
                MessageBox.Show("New proxy" + proxy.Address.ToString());
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
```

^^^ - Where i need to set the labels text, using Msgboxs at the moment but updating a label on the main form is obviously preferable

```
   foreach (string url in URLs)
        {
            result.URL = url;
            result.Shares = grabber.GetFacebookShares(url);
            result.Tweets = grabber.GetTweetCount(url);
            result.PlusOnes = grabber.GetPlusOnes(url);

            bgWorker.ReportProgress((outputGridView.Rows.Count * 100) / importGridView.Rows.Count, result);
        }
```

^^^ - Inside the bg workers do_work method on the main form.

2nd Edit*

I'm a bit new to events but could i not fire off a custom event say Proxy_Changed everytime i switch proxys and pass in a string argument with the new proxy/msg w.e and then subscribe to this event in the main form, then set the label on the main forms text = the string args when this event fires off? I'm probably talking jibberish tbh though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds from your question and subsequent comments to other answers that you are running your code within a WinForms project, correct me if I am wrong? In a winform the main program thread is usually always static (static void Main()) therefore you must make your EventHandler **static** also to avoid null exceptions. I believe this will resolve your issue as it sounds like the rest of your code is correct?

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I think the important parts of your class that needs to do the background works looks like:

```
public class Grabber
{
    public event EventHandler<MyArgs> NotifyParentUI;

    // other code.....

    public string Request(string action)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action))
        {
            return "";
        }

        HttpWebRequest req;

        string response = string.Empty;
        while (response.Equals(string.Empty) && proxy != null)
        {
            try
            {
                req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
                req.Proxy = proxy;
                response = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RemoveProxy(proxy);
                NotifyParentUI(this, new MyArgs() 
                   { Message = string.Format("Proxy Removed: {0}", proxy.Address.ToString()) });

                proxy = GenNewProx();
                NotifyParentUI(this, new MyArgs() 
                   { Message = string.Format("New Proxy: {0}", proxy.Address.ToString()) });
            }
        }

        return response;
    } 
}
```

In your main form you have a method to update your label that is thread-safe:

```
public void UpdateMyLabel(object sender, MyArgs ea)
{
    this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
        delegate()
        {
            labelControl1.Text = ea.Message;
        }
        ));
}
```

Also in the main form you must create an instance of your "grabber":

```
Grabber grabber = new Grabber();
grabber.NotifyParentUI += UpdateMyLabel;
```

You should have a method that runs on its own thread:

```
public void ThreadProc()
{

    // other code before this....

    foreach (string url in URLs)
    {
       result.URL = url;
       result.Shares = grabber.GetFacebookShares(url);
       Thread.Sleep(0); // may want to take the Sleeps out
       result.Tweets = grabber.GetTweetCount(url);
       Thread.Sleep(0);
       result.PlusOnes = grabber.GetPlusOnes(url);
       Thread.Sleep(0);
    }
}
```

Here's how you start the thread in the part of your main form:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
t.Start();
```

As a side note, if you need to pass data to your Thread, look here:
[Passing Data to Threads and Retrieving Data from Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts553s52%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Im not sure that would work. The labels text will only update when the worker has progress to report like i mentioned previously.

Inside the bg workers do work method, i have code that goes off and retrieves a few values, then stores them in a result List which is then passed to the ReportProgress method, which raises the ProgressChanged event. 

This means that the labels text will only update once we have finished retrieving some values and passed them to ReportProgress, this is not what i need.

Comment: The labels text needs to update each time a new proxy is selected/removed (happens in an outside class), however, this doesn't cause the workers progress changed event to fire. Hope i've explained the problem clearly

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it will work, however i'll be needlessly passing in an event everytime i call my Request method, is there a way around this?

Comment: I'm hoping that whenever you initially create your class that contains `Request`, you can pass in the event handler delegate at that time. It'll be global to this child class and you won't have to pass it around.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Are you talking about passing in 'EventHandler<MyArgs> myEvent' in the classes constructor? Or..?

Comment: @OldRed, check my EDITS. Yes, you can pass it in the constructor or you can set it the way above.

Comment: I've tried this and while it doesn't throw any errors, when the code to switch a proxy is called and this line: `myEvent(this, new MyArgs() { Message = string.Format("New Proxy: {0}", proxy.Address.ToString()) });` is executed, the whole process just ends without ever doing anything.

Comment: @OldRed, going to have to see your code in all the places you use myEvent and how you declare and set it. Plus, what's the event handler look like in your main form. Make sure myEvent is not null when called.

Comment: I'm using a global field instead of passing in myEvent, so NotifyParentUI is only called when i add/remove proxies as above. 

Then in my main form: `public SocialScraper()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gp.NotifyParentUI += UpdateMyLabel;
        }`
Where gp is the class containing the Request method. The delegate + custom event args class remain the same.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm doing except im using a background worker instead. It's almost as if the bg worker thread raises the 'RunWorkerComplete' event and ends the process when this line `NotifyParentUI(this, new MyArgs() 
                   { Message = string.Format("Proxy Removed: {0}", proxy.Address.ToString()) });` is reached. Here is the full code for the class that contains the Request Method: http://pastebin.com/qT3w2ehZ 

And here is the code for the Main form, removed some methods that are irrelevant: http://pastebin.com/Dun1CSgF

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9163/discussion-between-bradrem-and-oldred)

Answer (score 2):

Use Invoke method to run anonymous function on UI thread to update the label. For example:

```
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += (sender, args) =>
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
                            {
                                DoSomeWorkInBackground();

                                // Update the label in UI thread
                                MyOtherFormInstance.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                                                                            {
                                                                                MyOtherFormInstance.SetLabelText(i);
                                                                            });
                                DoSomOtherWorkInBackground();
                            }
                        };
```

In your Form:

```
    public void SetLabelText(int i)
    {
        myLabel.Text = i.ToString();
        // not sure that this needed, but try:
        myLabel.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: This works but the label only updates when the worker reports some progress, unless I'm misunderstanding your implementation? I'm using a property in the other class and setting it to the string i want displayed on the label on the Form, then passing this in e.g.:
­
myLabel.Text = gp.Status;

Comment: This seems like a more complicated way of just calling ProgressChanged. Why would this way be any better?

Comment: It is not better way. It is just another way. Sometimes you need to operate with UI inside of background worker thread. You can't do it by directly calling because UI objects should be accessed only from UI thread. So I showed you how to implement proper calling of functions in UI thread.

Comment: But BackgroundWorker is made specifically so you __can__ access the main UI thread through ProgressChanged and does the marshaling for you.  Unless your solution is quicker is some way, I think it's really only a step backwards. No?

Comment: It depends on your task. Sometimes have a lot of things should be called from background worker. For example, when you delete some files and found the file with readonly flag you should ask user for conformation. You do not want to stop a thread. Just want to suspend and show Yes/No/Cancel dialog to user. It can be implemented by my approach. So ProgressChanged could be used exactly as it named - for updating the progress of operation. All over more complicated things in UI thread could be done by Invoke.

Comment: OK, makes sense. I have another solution for him then.